# Basic AWS questions

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, scalability

I'm newbie on AWS, and it has so many products (EC2, Load Balancer, EBS, S3, SimpleDB etc.), and so many docs, that I can't figure out where I must start from.

My goal is to be ready for scalability.

1. Suppose I want to set up a simple webserver, which access a database in mongolab. I suppose I need one EC2 instance to run it. At this point, do I need something more (EBS, S3, etc.)?
2. At some point of time, my app has reached enough traffic and I must scale it. I was thinking of starting a new copy (instance) of my EC2 machine. But then it will have another IP. So, how traffic is distributed between both EC2 instances? Is that did automatically? Must I hire a Load Balancer service to distribute the traffic? And then will I have to pay for 2 EC2 instances and 1 LB? At this point, do I need something more (e.g.: Elastic IP)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Welcome to the club Sony Santos,

AWS is a very powerfull architecture, but with this power comes responsibility. I and presumably many others have learned the hard way building applications using AWS's services.

You ask, where do I start? This is actually a very good question, but you probably won't like my answer. You **need to read and do research** about all the technologies offered by amazon and even other providers such as Rackspace, GoGrid, Google's Cloud and Azure. Amazon is not easy to get going but its not meant to be really, its focus is more about being very customizable and have a very extensive api. But lets get back to your question.

1. To run a simple webserver you would need to start an EC2 instance this instance by default runs on a diskdrive called EBS. Essentially an EBS drive is a normal harddrive except that you can do lots of other cool stuff with it like take it off one server and move it to another. S3 is really more of a file storage system its more useful if you have a bunch of images or if you want to store a lot of backups of your databases etc, but its not a requirement for a simple webserver. Just running an EC2 instance is all you need, everything else will happen behind the scenes.
2. If you app reaches a lot of traffic you have two options. You can scale your machine up by shutting it off and starting it with a larger instance. Generally speaking this is the easiest thing to do, but you'll get to a point where you either cannot handle all the traffic with 1 instance even at the larger size and you'll decide you need two **OR** you'll want a more fault tolerant application that will still be online in the event of a failure or update.

   If you create a second instance you will need to do some form of loadbalancing. I recommend using amazons Elastic Load Balancer as its easy to configure and its integration with the cloud is better than using Round Robin DNS or a application like haproxy. Elastic Load Balancers are not expensive, I believe they cost around $18 / month + data that's passed between the loadbalancer.

   But no, you don't need anything else to do scale up your site. 2 EC2 instances and a ELB will do the trick.

Additional questions you didn't ask but probably should have.

1. How often does an EC2 instance experience hardware failure and crash my server. What can I do if this happens?

   It happens frequently, usually in batches. Sometimes I go months without any problems then I will get a few servers crash at a time. But its defiantly something you should plan for I didn't in the beginning and I paid for it. Make sure you create scripts and have backups and a backup plan ready incase your server fails. Be ok with it being down or have a load balanced solution from day 1.
2. Whats the hardest part about scalabilty?

   Testing testing testing testing... Don't ever assume anything. Also be prepared for sudden spikes in your traffic. You have to be prepared for anything if you page goes from 1 to 1000 people over night are you prepared to handle it? Have you tested what you "think" will happen?

Best of luck and have fun... I know I have :)

Comment: I've read just now about EC2 "ephemerality" (it's normal to crash frequently even with no much traffic), and I must be prepared for that (maybe with a service like CloudWatch). Thank you, and I *liked* your answer! :)

Comment: CloudWatch will only monitor instances performance, sometimes it might detect its down since they have 2 checks for connectivity but it doesn't always work correctly. Its best to have some 3rd party service check like pingdom or nagios etc... 

Being prepared for the crash is more than just knowing its down (though that's the first step) you need to make sure you can recover quickly. For the first few months I had my product in AWS I could barely sleep I spent so much time fixing stuff. But now I can sleep good knowing that a server crash will fix itself and wont cause downtime.

Comment: @bwight - regarding your second '1' - have you lost data that was written to an EBS drive?

Comment: Data no, server configuration files that i needed yes. Lost the servers quite a few times. Back in the middle of 2011 it was pretty problematic. Has died down a little but every month or two seems like another server crashes. I don't loose data anymore because i'm prepared so it doesn't bother me.

Comment: @bwight, what about Elastic Beanstalk? seem like it has something related to EC2

Comment: Beanstalk is good if you want to automate the whole process of launching your application in the cloud without having to write your own code to do it. May not be the perfect solution for everyone but I think its a good product.